# ManagementEventWatcher throws System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, winforms, process, wmi

I have a strange problem with the WMI ManagementEventWatcher, which I use to track the Start and End of processes.

```
public System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher process_spawn;
public System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher process_end;

public home_panel(){

        InitializeComponent();

    try{

        string scope = @"\\.\root\CIMV2"; // local machine

        process_spawn = new System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher(scope, "SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace");
        process_end = new System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher(scope, "SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace");

        process_spawn.EventArrived += new System.Management.EventArrivedEventHandler(process_spawned);

        process_end.EventArrived += new System.Management.EventArrivedEventHandler(process_ended);


        process_spawn.Start();
        process_end.Start();

    }catch(Exception exc){
        Console.WriteLine(exc);
    }
}

void process_spawned(object sender, System.Management.EventArrivedEventArgs e){
    process_spawn.Start();
    Console.WriteLine((string)e.NewEvent["ProcessName"]);
    //socket.Emit("process_started", (string)e.NewEvent["ProcessName"]);
}

void process_ended(object sender, System.Management.EventArrivedEventArgs e){
    process_spawn.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine((string)e.NewEvent["ProcessName"]);
    //socket.Emit("process_started", (string)e.NewEvent["ProcessName"]);
}
```

The problem is that when I run my program in debug mode of Visual Studio 2012 Express, everything works just fine, but when I run the .exe file it throws this exception:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Not enough memory to continue the execution of the program. 
at System.Management.ManagementScope.Initialize()
at System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher.Initialize()
at System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher.Start()
```

I hope someone can help me figure out what causes this exception.

Comment: The underlying error code for this exception is E_OUTOFMEMORY, a COM error code.  Which doesn't necessarily mean that your program is out of memory, it can also be a system resource like the kernel pool that's low.  If this error is consistent, even after a reboot, then your machine is borken.

Comment: Yes, I've checked the memory usage and the exception does definitely not refer to the physical available memory. I just don't get it why it does work without any errors when I start my program in Visual Studio Debug, but it doesn't when i run the .exe file itself.